# Need help understanding Linked Lists with recursion (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, nodes

I am working on a project that deals with a linked lists and nodes and I am struggling knowing what is not working so far. When I runt this code, all I am getting in return is just 19. Any explanation of what I am not understanding would be greatly appreciated.

```
    class Node:
"""
Represents a node in a linked list
"""
def __init__(self, data):
    self._data = data
    self._next = None

def get_data(self):
    return self._data

def set_data(self, newData):
    self._data = newData

def get_next(self):
    return self._next

def set_next(self, newNode):
    self._next = newNode

    class LinkedList:
"""
A linked list implementation of the List ADT
"""
def __init__(self):
    self._head = None

def get_head(self):
    """
    Returns head of node
    """
    return self._head

def rec_add(self, val, a_node):
    """
    A recursive method that adds a value to the linked list
    """

    # works for an empty list OR because it is recursive; will add the value when it reaches end of the list
    if a_node is None:
        self._head = Node(val)
        return self._head
    else:

        self._head.set_next(self.rec_add(val, a_node.get_next()))
        return self._head

def add(self, val):
    """
    Helper method for recursive add method
    """
    self._head = self.rec_add(val, self._head)

def rec_display(self, a_node):
    """recursive display method"""
    if a_node is None:
        return
    print(a_node.get_data(), end=" ")
    self.rec_display(a_node.get_next())

def display(self):
    """recursive display helper method"""
    self.rec_display(self.get_head())
```

This is what I am testing and just getting 19 to return:

```
    my_list = LinkedList()
    my_list.add(13)
    my_list.add(8)
    my_list.add(19)
    my_list.display()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to add new nodes to the end of your linked list then you do not want to be resetting `self._head` each time a new node is added:

```
def add(self, val):
    """
    Helper method for recursive add method
    """
    self._head = self.rec_add(val, self._head)
```

By doing so, your code makes the next node added the new head node and the link to the previous head node is lost.

Instead, you want to assign the head once, traverse the linked list until you get to the end, then add the new node to last node in the list:

```
    def rec_add(self, val, a_node):
        # works for an empty list OR because it is recursive; will add the value when it reaches end of the list
        if a_node.get_next() is None:
            a_node.set_next(Node(val))
            return
        else:
            self.rec_add(val, a_node.get_next())
            return

    def add(self, val):
        if self._head is None:
            self._head = Node(val)
        else:
            self.rec_add(val, self._head)
```

Comment: That makes so much sense... God bless you kind sir/ma'am, you have no idea how long I just sat there and looked at it wondering why it wasn't working!